# autocomplete text search

Tags: javascript

can any body tell me steps to use it, where i can get simple example for this

Comment: No. Not unless you provide more information. (Where to use it on what data for which purpose...)

Comment: There is jQuery UI solution http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Type 'google.com' into your browser address bar and then 'javascript autocomplete'

Answer (score 1):

yes, please follow the following steps

1. Download `jquery.ui` library from [here](http://jqueryui.com/). `jquery` comes with it.
2. link jquery library `<script src="jquery-someversion.js"></script>`
3. link `<link href="jquery.ui.someversion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
4. link jquery ui libarary `<script src="jquery.ui.someversion.js"></script>`
5. rest of the code is given [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). just click **`View Source`** link and you will find it.

**View source**

[image]

From some url

```
 $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source        : 'someurl.php'
    });
```

and on some URL, you can query your database with the parameter and print auto-complete data that will be displayed in your auto-complete.

Comment: where is view source experimentX

Comment: @vijauu see in updated picture

Comment: how can i use this to access my database elements and display in textbox

Comment: @vijauuu depends how you want to use it. you can point to some `url`. And on that `url`. see update. Also do some research.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is the jQuery UI autocomplete widget:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

It can use a simple array or an ajax call as the datasource.

Comment: thanks geon already i seened this code can u please tell me how can i fetch data from my database using jsp

Answer (score 0):

- [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
- [YUI Autocomplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/)
- [DOJO Filtering Select](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html)